# How to keep empty strings as parameters in rewrite hatches regexp

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url

I'm having trouble passing an empty parameter as url in a hatches rewrite condition.

My rewrite simple takes all the parameters splitter by / and passes them as php GET :

```
RewriteRule /?([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?$ index.php?option1=$1&option2=$2&option3=$3&option4=$4&option5=$5&option6=$6
```

but when I try this URL :

> ---.com/fiction//204

I get these GET parameters in php (note the double `/` in the url) :

```
Array ( 
[option1] => fiction 
[option2] => 204 
[option3] => 
[option4] => 
[option5] => 
[option6] => )
```

But I would like to have

```
Array ( 
[option1] => fiction 
[option2] =>  
[option3] => 204
[option4] => 
[option5] => 
[option6] => )
```

I tried adding an empty string to the rexexp : `(^$|[A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)` but this doesn't work..

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These empty values must be captured from `RewriteCond` since `RewriteRule` strips all multiple `/`s into single `/`.

This should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([\w-]*)(?:/([\w-]*)(?:/([\w-]*)(?:/([\w-]*)(?:/([\w-]*)(?:/([\w-]*))?)?)?)?)?/?$
RewriteRule ^ index.php?option1=%1&option2=%2&option3=%3&option4=%4&option5=%5&option6=%6 [L,QSA]
```

This rule makes every parameter after first parameter optional.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need these 6 rules instead of the one you have:

```
RewriteRule /([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?$ index.php?option1=$1&option2=$2&option3=$3&option4=$4&option5=$5&option6=$6
RewriteRule /([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?$ index.php?option1=$1&option2=$2&option3=$3&option4=$4&option5=$5
RewriteRule /([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?$ index.php?option1=$1&option2=$2&option3=$3&option4=$4
RewriteRule /([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?$ index.php?option1=$1&option2=$2&option3=$3
RewriteRule /([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?$ index.php?option1=$1&option2=$2
RewriteRule /([A-Z.a-z0-9_-]*)/?$ index.php?option1=$1
RewriteRule /$ index.php
```

But i'm not sure URLs with multiple consecutive slashes would work with all browsers & servers, i think it is generally bad idea.